# Fulltext on AppEngine Java . Searching substring (SDK 1.6.6)

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Searching for document containing a word e.g. *London* works. 
How do i define a search for a documents with (substring):

1. starting with "*Lond*"
2. or word ending with "*don*"
3. or word containing "*on*"

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring search is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine's full text search API does not support substring matching.

However you can invent a workaround for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10962212/66673) for a Python-based solution that should translate easily to Java.