# Search data in a Datastore with Python on GAE

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I have a `NDB` model `User` compose of `firstname`, `lastname`, `username` and `tag` fields. `tag` means all possible text that a user can search..

I can do search possible user by using the `tag` field...

Is their any other way a data can be search without the `tag` field? Or can I use `regex` while retrieving data in the Datastore?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't use regex
2. If you need to do Full Text Search, try the Search API https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

Comment: I am aiming the same output as a "LIKE" statement in mysql. .

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I think it might help.. :D

Comment: A like statement isn't possible with GAE.. even with the Search API, only whole words will be matched, not substrings

Comment: Well.. no. Unless you "manually" export all the substrings in a search field. Just to make clear what I said before, what I meant is that e.g. searching your name with something like leon won't return it. It will only be returned if you type leonard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960384/google-app-engine-python-search-api-string-search