# "LIKE a%". How to write this on app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using java with app engine.
SQL query:

> select * from Person where name LIKE "a%"

How to write it on Google App Engine?

Comment: Are you using the datastore or an SQL database?

Comment: Why was this closed? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Do you need to do only this particular case (case-sensitive, fixed prefix string search) or a general LIKE search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for the LIKE operator in Appengine's datastore.

Two solutions :

- Use Google Cloud SQL if you want to keep SQL-like queries
- Use [Full Text Search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) with you entities in the datastore

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're querying against an entity in the App Engine datastore, in Java you'd rewrite `LIKE "a%"` into something like

```
Query query = new Query("Person")
  .addFilter("name", QueryFilterOperater.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, "a")
  .addFilter("name", QueryFilterOperator.LESS_THAN, "b");
```

The rest is left as an exercise. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

Comment: This does not address the question (how to do LIKE) at all. Looking at the other answers, that seems to be non-trivial, not something "to be left as an exercise".

Comment: Look again. This rewrights LIKE "a%" into >= "a" AND < "b".

Comment: Okay, in this particular case (the pattern is just a case-sensitive fixed prefix), that would be an alternative to using LIKE. But I did not get that at all from your answer. Add a bit of explanation, and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: "This particular case" is the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

To perform such query you have to use [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide).

If you're using Datastore, so it doesn't support fulltext search. You have to manually create all possible variations of name and use them to query entities. You can store them in special entity's multivalued field (it can be expensive) or use special [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) that perfectly fit this purpose (Search doesn't support substring matching so you have to use variations all the same).

It two words working with Search API is:

1. List item Create Person entity in Datastore with some `name`
2. Create corresponding Document in search Index named `Persons`, with fields `possible_names` and `entity_id` (also you can use Document.doc_id to store entity's id). In `possible_names` you store all useful variations of name divided by space.
3. Query `Persons` index to find all documents where field `possible_names` matches your search string.
4. Use field `entity_id` form result's Documents to retrieve entity from Datastore by id.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960384/google-app-engine-python-search-api-string-search) is little example.

Comment: LIKE is not full text search, though.

Comment: Can you explain why? By `fulltext search` I mean searching some string by some pattern in some text without using some index. LIKE does exactly it, isn't it?

Comment: Fulltext search usually means something like Lucene, or that Search API you linked to (which, like you point out does not support substring matching). In particular, it generally does not match arbitrary (non-token) patterns that a LIKE search (which is substring matching) could.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this    `"select * from Person where name LIKE \"a%\""`