# implementing search functionality in google cloud platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, full-text-search

Hi I am implementing search functionality using Full Text Search(document api) of google app engine

following is the procedure how i have saved data in my documents

**For instance if user enters  "hello world" then i save "hello world h he hel hell hello w wo wor worl world" in my documents** as shown in this question ([Google App Engine (python) : Search API : String Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960384/google-app-engine-python-search-api-string-search/10962212))

it is working fine WRT following examples

if I have a string in db "this is a amazing and beautiful house" and now if I will search

- "this"   ---> this will work
- "this is a amazing"   ---> this will work
- "beautiful house"   ---> this will work

**but if i will search "amazing house" this will not work**

I want it to work this way too

Can you guys suggest some idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my method of making query for search, there are specific ways how you can make query in documents for example

\"search key words\"   --->  this will look for the exact match in documents (in my case I was making query like this which was wrong)

"search key words"   ---> Retrieves documents that contains at least one occurrence of the words irrespective if their order

for more details kindly view this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/query_strings#Python_Queries_on_text_and_HTML_fields